# Convert StructureMap to Autofac

Tags: autofac, structuremap

Does anyone know how to convert this to Autofac syntax?

```
private static IElementGenerator<T> GetGenerator<T>(T model) where T : class
{
      var library = StructuremapMvc.ParentScope.CurrentNestedContainer.GetInstance<HtmlConventionLibrary>();
      return ElementGenerator<T>.For(library, t => StructuremapMvc.ParentScope.CurrentNestedContainer.GetInstance(t), model);
}
```

Here is the link to the code

https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversity/blob/master/src/ContosoUniversity/Infrastructure/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs

Comment: Could you describe what your code is doing ? `IElementGenerator` doesn't seem to be a StructureMap things.

Comment: The code is as per the github link.

Comment: This appears to have also been filed as a [question issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/740)